# Font Awesome Styling

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

I'm trying to style four Font Awesome icons, but it appears when I bring them below 10px in height and width, the hover state gets messed up.

The goal is to have them display in white and have a hover effect that changes the icon to red with a white background. Thoughts?

If it helps, I'm putting this in a bootstrap nav. Also, if you're comfortable with the newest Bootstrap, I can't seem to overlay the navbar on top of a Bootstrap Carousel instead pushing the Carousel down.

**CSS**

```
#socialnav .fa {
    font-size: 1em;
    color: #ffffff;
    width:10px;
    height:10px;
    text-align:center;
    padding: 5px;
    transition:all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

#socialnav .fa:hover {
    color: #c9001f;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<section id="socialnav">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-inverse">
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navigation">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto w-100 justify-content-end">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fa fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fa fa-youtube" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</section>
```

Answer (score 2):

Set height and width to relative, you don't want to set a static height and width to the icon or else the background will be exactly 10 pixels in height and width. Check out my codepen for a working example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QgPboZ?editors=1111

```css
#socialnav .fa {
 font-size: 1em;
 color: #ffffff;
 width: relative;
 height: relative;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 5px;
 transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

#socialnav .fa:hover {
 color: #c9001f;
 background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<section id="socialnav">
 <nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-inverse">
  <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navigation">
   <ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto w-100 justify-content-end">
    <li class="nav-item">
     <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
     <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
     <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fa fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
     <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fa fa-youtube" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
    </li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </nav>
</section>
```

Comment: That got me going in the right direction. Any idea how I could specify the sizes though? The icons are still too large. I reduced the height of the nav - I ultimately want to lose it when a user is on a mobile device - and the hover state isn't displaying correctly.

Comment: @I.Green you can adjust the size of FontAweomse with `font-size` e.g `.fa { font-size: 9px }`

Comment: @I.Green Or use `fa-2x`, `fa-3x`, `fa-4x`, or `fa-5x`